# EmberData belongsTo not working with just ID

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create a belongsTo relation, but i am always getting the following error:

> Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: You must include
>   an `id` in a hash passed to `push`

My model definition looks like this:

```
GambifyApp.Bet = DS.Model.extend({
    scoreT1: DS.attr('string'),
    scoreT2: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

Within my Json return I have simply

```
{
id:128433, 
user:8926, 
points:0, 
game:94, 
scoreT1:2, 
scoreT2:2
}
```

The user value under user is my user id. Regarding Documentation(http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships) it should look exactly like this. But its causing me this error. If I change my "user" property to an attribute everything is working fine.

Update:
Found the problem in my serializer that is extracting all relations and adds them as sideloaded models. Of course it was not handling the case where this relation is only an id instread of the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't including the data associated with `user` the relationship should be async.

```
GambifyApp.Bet = DS.Model.extend({
    scoreT1: DS.attr('string'),
    scoreT2: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async:true})
});
```

Comment: Thats what I thought, too. But its not fixing the issue. (I am not sure if it makes a difference, but the user is already sideloaded, so its not necessary to do another request.)